# Eclipse stopped working after i downloaded a standalone STS

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse oxygen stopped working today after i downloaded an unrelated, standalone version of Spring Tools Suite. When trying to run it, i get the following popup dialog: "Error opening Welcome dialog: Failed to create improved startup dialog, falling back to Eclipse standard dialog. Please check Eclipse configuration logs for details.". Here is the error code generated in txt file by eclipse:

```
!SESSION 2018-02-02 02:30:05.480 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2018-02-02 02:30:07.831
!MESSAGE Error opening Welcome dialog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2018-02-02 02:30:07.835
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.showCustomDialog(IDEApplication.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.dialogs.custom.CustomStartupDialog.promptOld(CustomStartupDialog.java:406)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.dialogs.custom.CustomStartupDialog.prompt(CustomStartupDialog.java:298)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: C:\Users\Korisnik\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.7.100.v20170517-1755.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.enrichExceptionWithBaseFile(ZipBundleEntry.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.StorageUtil.getBytes(StorageUtil.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:566)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:159)
    ... 43 more
Root exception:
java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.FormToolkit
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.dialogs.custom.CustomStartupDialog.promptOld(CustomStartupDialog.java:406)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.startup.dialogs.custom.CustomStartupDialog.prompt(CustomStartupDialog.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.showCustomDialog(IDEApplication.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: C:\Users\Korisnik\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.7.100.v20170517-1755.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.enrichExceptionWithBaseFile(ZipBundleEntry.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.StorageUtil.getBytes(StorageUtil.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:566)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:159)
    ... 43 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-02 02:30:09.633
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/FormToolkit
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.showCustomDialog(IDEApplication.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Comment: Why don't you add STS to your existing Eclipse? https://o7planning.org/en/10249/install-spring-tool-suite-into-eclipse  or add whatever plugins you had to the (working?) Standalone STS Eclipse?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391845/exception-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-trying-to-open-allure-reports-in-w#comment121147474_67756207

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is a framework. [STS](https://spring.io/tools) is (from the link) *a customized all-in-one Eclipse based distribution that makes application development easy.* Your assertion that Eclipse is unrelated to Eclipse is just unfounded. The only solution I know is to point to different workspaces if you really need to have separate Eclipse instances.