# Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to open allure-reports in webdriver.io project

Tags: java, eclipse, webdriver, allure

I have a small webdriver.io project just for experimenting with it for the first time. I now wanted to add allure reports but when I try to run `allure open` I get the following exception and I have no idea where I have to look to resolve this:

```
Starting web server...
2021-05-04 22:06:43.669:INFO::main: Logging initialized @349ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2630)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1399)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1397)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1396)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1429)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported(Desktop.java:328)
        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.openBrowser(Commands.java:220)
        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.open(Commands.java:152)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:165)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at io.qameta.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:88)
```

The reports are getting generated just fine. Only when I try to open them I get this error.

I have allure-reporter and allure-commandline installed via npm. I have my project inside a Debian WSL and run chromedriver with VcXsrv X Server in case this might help.

Does anybody have an idea how this error might get resolved or have a hint for what to look for? I hope I gave you enough information. If not, just say what you need. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have removed the unanswered "followup" question, since this Q&A has turned into the canonical dup target for this kind of question.  If for some reason you still need an answer to the followup, ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

on ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

As Joakim suggested [in this comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391845/exception-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-trying-to-open-allure-reports-in-w#comment119119464_67391949), the headless version was installed. I got the same error with ldd, the library missing.

It's not a good idea to change your question in general, it's better to search first and ask a new one if needed, with all specifics.

This may help you understand the possible cause of the second issue:

[Desktop API is not supported on the current platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004150/desktop-api-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform)

I highly recommend to use a plain Ubuntu Linux installation if you want to use Linux, WSL is not the same and has specific issues that you will not encounter in Linux. If a dedicated install is not an option, try to look for generic issues. Expect differences in behavior with shells, docker and graphical related things, because those things are specifically implemented in certain ways for WSL.

Comment: I have searched for that general issue but haven't found anything, thanks for the link! And you are right, next time I will post a new questions, that was dumb.

Comment: This also worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 to fix my Eclipse IDE startup error which said: `Failed to create improved startup dialog, falling back to Eclipse standard dialog. Please check Eclipse configuration logs for details.`

Comment: I had open jdk 11 already installed. But something was missing. I did the following
sudo apt install apt-file,
sudo apt-file update,
and then again
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
after that it works. Found here https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/java-programs-stopped-working/24091/5

Comment: Oh yeah, just ran into the same problem with a completely different little app I wrote and my test system was being built with the JRE instead. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Same on Fedora, you should install `java-11-openjdk-devel` to have everything for Java development and avoid this error.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well. Thanks!.

Answer (score 8):

**[For me it worked]**

When you get this kinda error it means in installation of your jdk some of files are missed. To solve this problem act like bellow:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-[version]-jdk --fix-missing
```

eg.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jdk --fix-missing
```

it means  you already installed the jdk but there are some missing files with it. So you can fix it as easy as a pice of cake just by using '--fix-missing'

Comment: running Open Visual Traceroute... this fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You likely have some missing downstream libraries.

Run this to find out which ones, then install them.

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
```

> ```
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The BROWSE action is not supported on the current platform!
>        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.checkActionSupport(Desktop.java:380)
>        at java.desktop/java.awt.Desktop.browse(Desktop.java:524)
>        at io.qameta.allure.Commands.openBrowser(Commands.java:222)
> ```

That means WSL doesn't support `java.awt.Desktop.browse()`.

This has been brought up before in Stackoverflow.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27881223/775715

Comment: When I run this I get: `ldd: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so: No such file or directory`

Comment: You are missing that lib, perhaps you installed the headless version of your openjdk package?

Comment: I can't remember how I installed openjdk but installing openjdk-11-jdk again resolved that error. But now I'm getting a different error. I'll add it at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Ok thanks, so there is no way to get this running?

Comment: For the BROWSE action issue see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004150/desktop-api-is-not-supported-on-the-current-platform . Installing the mentioned Gnome library may work: sudo apt-get install libgnome2-0. Also check yourself on the expected URL and port if the app runs, it basically attempts to open the browser for you, which fails because of a lack of implementation of the class.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is simple i had the problem and i solved it by:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt upgrade openjdk-11-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.4.1.1-1.fc36.x86_64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
This error requires an updat of the jdk.

1. Download the current update from Oracle support jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm
2. sudo rpm -ivh jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm
   this will install libawt_headless.so and it is working
   Operating System deployed to is Fedora36

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/lib/libawt_xawt.so
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2633)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2501)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2700)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2651)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1395)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1393)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1392)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1425)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Insets.<clinit>(Insets.java:89)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.<clinit>(SynthLookAndFeel.java:75)
        at snowflake.App.main(App.java:67)
```

If you get this error on Manjaro Linux when running any Java program (in my case SnowFlake), then you need to install openjdk11-src, jre11-openjdk, jdk11-openjdk